# Replace Values Conditionals

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to replace values based on certain conditions. I can do this for the values in a specific column but I am not sure how to convert the code to have it work for all values in a range of columns.

This is my code currently:

```
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
ColumnNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
Step1 = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,
                           each[L1_Grade],
                           else if Text.Contains([L1_Grade], "A") then "Upper"
                           else if Text.Contains([L1_Grade], "B") then "Middle" 
                           else if Text.Contains([L1_Grade], "C") then "Lower"
                           else if Text.Contains([L1_Grade], "NaN") then ""
                           else if Value.Is(Value.FromText([L1_Grade]), type number) then "Num"
                           else [L1_Grade], Replacer.ReplaceText, ColumnNames)
in
    Step1
```

How do I modify my code so it works for any of the columns specified using `ColumnNames`? I am not sure what to replace `[L1_Grade]` with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have such table:

[image]

Then you may use following code:

```
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Data"]}[Content], 
  replace = Table.ReplaceValue(
    Source, 
    0, 
    0, 
    (a, b, c) =>
      let
        f = (x) => Text.Contains(a, x), 
        y = try Number.From(a) otherwise a
      in
        if y is number and not Number.IsNaN(y) then
          "Num"
        else if f("A") then
          "Upper"
        else if f("B") then
          "Middle"
        else if f("C") then
          "Lower"
        else if f("NaN") then
          ""
        else
          a, 
    Table.ColumnNames(Source)
  )
in
  replace
```

[image]

Some comments:

1. Of course, you may use different list of columns in the last argument of the function.
2. The code may be simplified, if numbers are always as type text and/or may be only single version of "NaN".
3. If the replacement logic should be case-sensitive - adjust this line:

   ```
    f = (x) => Text.Contains(a,x,Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
   ```

But since "NaN" contains "a" letter, some other code changes are required.